# Error: None of [Index(['..'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]

Tags: object, indexing, keyerror, dtype

I have a dataframe with the following results (this is a snippet of the dataframe relevant to my question).

```
   researchAndDevelopment operatingExpenses  ... depreciationAndAmortization  \
0                     0.0          43908000  ...                     7741000   
1                     0.0        5539610.51  ...                  1259992.79   
2                     0.0           2446000  ...                      757000   
3                     0.0                 0  ...                           0
```

I want to return the first row (row 0) value for the researchAndDevelopment column and am using:

```
df.loc[["researchAndDevelopment"]].iloc[0,0]
```

It should return 0, however, I'm receiving the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['researchAndDevelopment'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot the issue?